# How to keep my iPhone application in listening mode?

Tags: core-audio, openal, avaudiorecorder, ios5

i want to keep my audio listening always on means i want my app to listen to the sounds but not record them. need to get the details of the sounds like frequency etc . Like the app "Talking tom" or apps like this are .It will be very helpful if some one guide me how to i start or use which technique , any sample or demo will be very helpful  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Both the iOS Audio Queue API and the RemoteIO Audio Unit can be used to return raw PCM audio samples from the mic to a buffer callback (you don't have to save them to a file first).  These audio recording APIs can run until stopped (or the app becomes non-active).

Apple has sample iOS apps using each of these APIs on their iOS developer site.  Look for SpeakHere and aurioTouch.